# Array field into MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database

I need your help with a db question on MySQL. I have a table containing spots with several properties about each spot, and an user table containing properties for each user. How to store into database the spots a user subscribed to ?
Currently I have a field containing a Json array, which I decode and re-encode each time I need to access and modify. But a direct mysql request can't support it so complexity is quickly so important...

How would you structure your dB in such a situation?

Comment: Check the answer below. That will make it easier rather than the decoding and re-encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Have your fields in different colums in a table instead of just one for the Json array.

You can try a join operation on both tables. That way you wont need to decode and re-encode your Json array.

Downside being it will take up more storage space.

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I did it with inner join that works but I was not sure it was a good solution ! Will market this thread as solved ;)